# Import error with remote interpreter in pycharm

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, interpreter

I am trying to run my code in the server using ssh remote interpreter.

The connection and the deployment work but when I want to import libraries located in the server it gives an import error

> ssh://***@****.com:22/usr/bin/python -u
>
> /home/***/main.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/***/main.py", line 11,
>   in 
>       from clplibs.clp import ContinuousLearningPlatform as clp ImportError: No module named clplibs.clp
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: So you want the error to be fixed. What have you tried?

Comment: I do not know what I should try, Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: can you run the script on the server without pycharm?

Comment: yes that worked. I want to be able to run/debug it from Pycharm. Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution, the environment variables (including python path) should be defined from pycharm: Run/Debug configurations-> Environment variables. Pycharm won't use bashrc paths.